# Report Builder - Average of field if another field = X

Tags: average, reportbuilder3.0

I'm just beginning with Report Builder and I am trying to get an average of the value of one field if another field equals a number.

Example:

A table that contains a series of book reviews by different reviewers identified by number:

```
Reviewer     Score
1            95 
2            85
3            77
3            99  
1            87
```

What I want is to get a reviewer's overall average score. So i would like to get an average of all scores filtering out the other reviewers.

I have been at this for a couple hours now and I don't think I am even close...

Answer (score 0):

```
=Avg(iif(reviewer="1",score,Nothing))
```

I have used this successfully in my report.